# Is this code vulnerable to DOM based attacks?

Tags: web-application, attacks, xss, vulnerability, dom

We are developing code for a Banking web application. We want to make sure that the code is secure and since we are using a lot of javascript code, we are kind of worried if any chance of a web based attack can surface. Can someone please look into the code below and comment if any attack could be possible by an attacker? The below code is within a jsp page.

> window.location.href = document.getElementById("st_val").value

```
st_val
```

is a hidden field on the form which contains either of 3 values, that is used by the Java code on the backend to decide on a logic.

Comment: We don't tend to do code reviews. There's another site for that. The other big question in your code becomes "what happens when the id value is not one of the 3 expected ones?"

Comment: @schroeder - is this a new policy?  I feel like i've seen a million questions like this and they are usually pretty well received.

Comment: If it isn't one of the three values, we are setting the boolean flag to null. Its only a small logic. Java code handles this.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be problem as long as **st_val** is NOT under the client control. As you know, if you are setting value of the window.location.href variable it will redirect current page to the new value. If attacker set **javascript:alert(1)** value to the **st_val** this will be end up with DOM XSS.

For example;

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
Hello
<script>
function onSubmit(){
        window.location.href = document.getElementById("st_val").value;
}
</script>
        <input type="hidden" id="st_val" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['pay']) ? $_GET['pay'] : '')?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return onSubmit();">
</html>
```

Attacker sends following request. http://domain.com/xss/href.php?pay=javascript:alert(1)

**alert(1)** function will be called immiadetly when you clicked on submit button.

In conclusion, it's safe to use **window.location.href** as long as values comes from your backend, without client decision!

Comment: Thank you, Mehmet. This cleared up a bit for me. st_value is something that is coming from the backend. We are setting its value. I hope this must be fine.
From what I understand, as long as the value is not set using request parameters that are controlled by the user, we must be fine. It makes sense. :)

Comment: And whatever input you are taking from client using request parameters must be sanitized and validated.